# Javascript showing all classes not just one

Tags: javascript, php

Good day good people

I have a bit of a conundrum

I have javascript code that works as it supposed to 
But when clicking the show all button it displays all the hidden items for all the classes and not just for the one you clicked

Javascript code in php block

```
$(function () {
$('.result".$h."').slice(0, 5).show();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('span').click(function () {
        $('.result".$h."').slice(0, 1000).show();
        $('this').hide();
  });
});
```

PHP Code Snippet

```
$h=1;

foreach ($nbResult as $key => $brand) {
    echo "
    <tr class='result".$h."' style='display:none; border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f; align-right'>
    <td style='padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px; color: #2f2f2f'>" . $brand['email'] . " </td>
    </tr>
    ";
    }
    echo "<tr><td><span class='loadMore'>SHOW ALL</span></td></tr>";

$h++;
```

Edit:
Sorry I missed copying the incrementing

Comment: *it displays all the sections and not just the one* Which part of the code is doing that? Please rephrase your question to include more relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not incrementing the value of `$h` variable.

Check this

```
$h=1;

    foreach ($nbResult as $key => $brand) {
        echo "
        <tr class='result".$h."' style='display:none; border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f; align-right'>
        <td style='padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px; color: #2f2f2f'>" . $brand['email'] . " </td>
        </tr>
        ";
$h++;
        }
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>
        <span class='loadMore'>SHOW ALL</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: That does not seem to work, the browser shows eg class=result5 and result6 but when clicking the show all button under result5 it shows result6 as well

Comment: your span class is defined outside of the loop. not anywhere else

Comment: Thats correct, if I add it in the loop I will have multiple spans instead of just one

Comment: give that dynamic value to span and check